# Pinging Ip's and returning up/down status AND latency

Tags: python, ip, ping

I am using python and I am using a method like this

```
def ping(host):
# Ping parameters as function of OS
parameters = "-n 1" if system_name().lower()=="windows" else "-c 1"

# Pinging
return system_call("ping " + parameters + " " + host) == 0
```

to get the up/down status of the list of ip's I am pinging.  Is there a way to extract the latency from this as well?

My output when running this code looks something along the lines of

```
Ping statistics for x.x.x.x:
Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 50ms, Maximum = 50ms, Average = 50ms
x.x.x.x is down
```

I would it to say x.x.x.x is down, latency = 50ms.  Is there a simple way to do this that I am overlooking?

Comment: You'll have to parse the output of `system_call`.  What is that function? Did you define it?

Comment: `from os import system as system_call`

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to parse the output. oh well haha.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).  From the docs on [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system):

> Changes to sys.stdin, etc. are not reflected in the environment of the executed command. If command generates any output, it will be sent to the interpreter standard output stream.

Subprocess will just be easier.

Comment: I'll do some research on it